# Inno Setup remove/hide/disable the NextButton on a custom wizard page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to disable the "Next" button from my custom wizard page.
The fact is that I've no issue to change the caption of it for example, but if I set the `NextButton.Enabled` to `False`, Inno Setup show me the Welcome page instead of my Custom Page. Any Idea?

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := 'test'; { Works }
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := false ; { delete my custom page }
  WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := 'Finish';  
end;

procedure CreateTheWizardPages;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  TestConnectivityButton: TButton;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Connectivity Test', '');
  CurPageChanged(Page.ID);
  TestConnectivityButton := TButton.Create(Page);
  TestConnectivityButton.Width := ScaleX(100);
  TestConnectivityButton.Height := ScaleY(30);
  TestConnectivityButton.Caption := CustomMessage('TestConnectivityAccessButtonLabel');
  TestConnectivityButton.OnClick := @TestConnectivityWindow;
  TestConnectivityButton.Parent := Page.Surface; 
 end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CreateTheWizardPages;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the changes, when you enter your custom page only – When `CurPageChanged` event function is called with `CurPageID` equal to `Page.ID`.

And you cannot call `CurPageChanged` yourself!

```pascal
var
  Page: TWizardPage;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = Page.ID then
  begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := 'Test';
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False ;
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := 'Finish';  
  end;
end;

procedure CreateTheWizardPages;
var
  TestConnectivityButton: TButton;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Connectivity Test', '');
  TestConnectivityButton := TButton.Create(Page);
  TestConnectivityButton.Width := ScaleX(100);
  TestConnectivityButton.Height := ScaleY(30);
  TestConnectivityButton.Caption :=
    CustomMessage('TestConnectivityAccessButtonLabel');
  TestConnectivityButton.OnClick := @TestConnectivityWindow;
  TestConnectivityButton.Parent := Page.Surface; 
end;
```

[image]

---

Another option is using `Page.OnActivate` event instead of `CurPageChanged` event function.